# Add number in ip number (172.17.14.65)

Tags: oracle, plsql-developer

I want to add number in ip number. for example
ip Number = 172.17.14.65 and i want to add one number ,let say
172.17.14.65+1 = output like 172.17.14.66

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Parse to separate octets values, build single 32-bit unsigned integer, add needed offset, perform backward transformation.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221720/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-calculate-range-ip-for-ipv6-cidr/43226773#43226773 Would be `Decimal2IP(IP2Decimal(ip) + 1, 4)`

Answer (score 1):

If you split the IP address into two parts, then add `1` to the last *digit* and concatenate both substrings to get the result. See comments within code.

Pay attention to valid values, though! For IPv4 `255` is the *max* value you can have, so adding `1` to it will result in `256` which is **invalid**.

```
SQL> with test (ip) as
  2    (select '172.17.14.65'  from dual union all
  3     select '172.17.14.255' from dual              --> note "255"
  4    )
  5  select
  6    ip,
  7    -- this returns "172.17.14."
  8    substr(ip, 1, instr(ip, '.', 1, 3)) ||
  9    -- this returns "65" and adds "1" to it
 10    to_char(to_number(substr(ip, instr(ip, '.', 1, 3) + 1)) + 1) result
 11  from test;

IP            RESULT
------------- -----------------------------------------------------
172.17.14.65  172.17.14.66
172.17.14.255 172.17.14.256       --> note 256 (invalid value)

SQL>
```